# PHP / cURL on Windows install: "The specified module could not be found."

Tags: php, windows, curl

I'm running PHP 5.2.3 on Windows 2000 Server with IIS 5.  I'm trying
to get cURL working, so in my **php.ini** file, I have this line:

> extension_dir ="F:\PHP\ext"

And later, I have:

> extension=php_curl.dll

The file **F:\PHP\ext\php_curl.dll** exists, but when I try to run any PHP
script, I get this in the error log:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'F:\PHP\ext
>   \php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>    in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Problem solved!

Although the error message said **The specified module could not be found**, this is a little misleading -- it's not that it couldn't find `php_curl.dll`, but rather it couldn't find a module that `php_curl.dll` required.  The 2 DLLs it requires are `libeay32.dll` and `SSLeay32.dll`.

So, you have to put those 2 DLLs somewhere in your PATH (e.g., `C:\Windows\system32`).  That's all there is to it.

However, even that did not work for me initially.  So I downloaded the Windows zip of the latest version of PHP, which includes all the necessary DLLs.  I didn't reinstall PHP, I just copied all of the DLLs in the "ext" folder to my PHP extensions folder (as specified in the `extension_dir` variable in `php.ini`), and I copied the versions of `libeay32.dll` and `SSLeay32.dll` from the PHP download into my System32 directory.

I also did an iisreset, but I don't know if that was necessary.

Comment: For me it was necessary to restart iis!

Comment: I had to do the same with `libssh2.dll` too.

Comment: Thanks @GrayFox Also had to add `libssh2.dll`, didn't work with `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` only.

Comment: `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` have been renamed to `libcrypto-*.dll` and `libssl-*.dll`

Comment: For anyone still struggling... I didnt have to do any of these dlls, not even sure where to get them from. As previous answers indicated, all I had to do is add php home dir in Windows system path and reboot (didnt work when I didnt reboot)

Answer (score 15):

`libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` have to be path-accessible for `php_curl.dll` to work correctly.

In **Control Panel** -> **Search** -> **Advanced System Settings** and use the button **Environment Variables**.

Under **System Variables** find **Path** add the `c:/php` folder (or whatever path) and restart Apache.

Comment: Worked for me.  I had to restart Windows to get the environment variable change to take effect however.  I have Apache manually installed from Apache Lounge, added as a service.

Comment: @elQuique awesome thanks this saved me - couldn't get cURL working until I added the ENV var!

Answer (score 5):

A tip is to use the [WAMP-installer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). Everything just works. It's not IIS though - so if it is important - you should ignore my advice. ;)

EDIT: I saw that you found the solution so I voted it up. +1

Comment: You still need to include libeay32.dll and SSLeay32.dll onto the system path when installing with xampp. Not sure about the WAMP installer though. But something to be mindful of.

Comment: Should mention that it uses Apache instead of just saying "not IIS".

Answer (score 1):

I keep having same problem although i did the suggestion above and many others suggested on the internet i get

> Sorry, but this plugin requires libcurl to be activated on your
>   server.

When i try to activate my plugin.

Edited: I was using php 5.3.13 had win64 windows 7 and none of the soln was working for me.

1.I had tried to copy the libeay32.dll SSLeay32.dll in windows\system32 folder did not work
2. Edited and uncommented both php.ini files did not work
3. Activated php_curl in php extensions did not work
4. Copied and replaced several times the [www.anindya.com](http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/) version of php_curl.dll but seems i was downloading the wrong version of this. The version that worked for me was in Fixed curl extensions section the second file php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64

Hope this will help anyone else

Comment: If you're still having trouble, you might want to ask this as a new question, noting that you tried the suggestions from this question already, and providing more details about your situation.  E.g., what OS, webserver, plugin, etc. are you working with?

Answer (score 1):

Faced this problem when I upgraded the php in UwAmp to 7.2.*. The only solution that worked for me was to download the latest version of apache at the time (Apache/2.4.37 (Win32)) and replace the one that came with UwAmp. That also involved editing the sample httpd.conf to produce an httpd_uwamp.conf file. UwAmp needs this template to then generate the actual httpd.conf when it starts up. All other suggestions above didn't resolve it for me unfortunately. Also note that as of OpenSSL 1.1, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll are no longer required (see http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php)

Comment: This was the only thing which worked for me too.
I had to update both Apache and PHP (Win32-vs16-x86) and copy/paste both uwamp ini files in order to definitely fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your case just add "F:\PHP\ext" to Environment Variable "path".