# Apache on Windows cant find php extensions

Tags: php, apache, ldap, apache2, windows-server-2012-r2

I have Apache 2.4 and php installed on Windows Server 2012.

Im trying to load the `php_ldap.dll` extension.

Here's what Ive done:

In `php.ini` I set the following:

```
extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"

extension=php_ldap.dll
```

Then, I made sure the dll was available at that path, yep, it's there:

[image]

`phpinfo` shows that I am editing the correct `php.ini` and the `extension_dir` is updated.

However, when I start Apache, `php_ldap.dll` is not loaded.

The Apache logs show this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\php\\ext\\php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

**How can I fix this?**

Also, what's with the `\\`? Why is it doubling the "\" and is that the problem?

Comment: double \\ is for escaping the first \ and no it is not the problem

Comment: I am not sure if that is the issue but try replacing extension_dir = "C:\php\ext" with extension_dir = "C:\php\ext\"

Comment: Notice that the ldap extension also needs the following two libraries `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`. You need to make sure so these two libraries are in your `PATH`, for example under `C:\Windows\System32`. http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348/php-curl-on-windows-install-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found also have a look if here it might lead you somewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess would be that a needed library is missing from your system. The `php_ldap` extensions requires that both `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` is  installed on the system:

From the [ldap installation manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php):

> Note: Note to Win32 Users
>
> In order for this extension to work, there are DLL files that must be
> available to the Windows system PATH. For information on how to do
> this, see the FAQ entitled "How do I add my PHP directory to the PATH
> on Windows". Although copying DLL files from the PHP folder into the
> Windows system directory also works (because the system directory is
> by default in the system's PATH), this is not recommended. This
> extension requires the following files to be in the PATH: libeay32.dll
> and ssleay32.dll Versions before PHP 4.3.0 additionally require
> libsasl.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use backslash in the php.ini !

Always slash in the php.ini even on Windows system.

```
extension_dir = "C:/php/ext"

extension=php_ldap.dll
```

Comment: While this may be good advice, its probably better suited as a comment than an answer since it doesn’t actually address the problem

Comment: i had the same extension problem on my windows system.  extension_dir = "C:/phpintalldir/ext" vas the key.