# Curl not enable wamp

Tags: php, apache, curl

**Problem**

Curl working for 7.2 but not working for 5.6 Wamp

1. Few months back I installed wamp then I uninstall it and use xamp 7.2.
2. But now I install wamp and set the PHP version 5.6.
3. (**wamp**) When I check the phpinfo curl not show for 5.6, But when I change the PHP version to 7.2 curl is showing.
4. Curl version showing in cmd 7.55.1

**What I tried**

1. I added **php_curl.dll** in php5.6./ext and apache bin folder and remove the semicolon in php.in
2. I also added curl.cainfo="c:/wamp/cacert.pem"

   But still curl not enable for 5.6

**Error log**

> [20-Dec-2019 12:02:35 UTC] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.40/ext/php_curl.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
> in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP / cURL on Windows install: "The specified module could not be found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348/php-curl-on-windows-install-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

Comment: I already did it but still it's not working

Comment: I think you are editing the wrong php ini file.

Comment: @thmspl I edit php.ini file in this folder php-5.6

Comment: And why do you want to change your php version? PHp 5.6 is no longer supported and EOL.

Comment: I am working on Codeigniter project in which MongoDB is used. Mongo version is compatible with 5.6 version. Because its client project it's worked on his server in which php vesion 5.6 and mongo version 3.0 something When I used this project with 7.2 in my local then in whole project I got a lot of errors like this thing is depreciated etc etc