PHP is unable to load CURL module on a local machine
I have these installations:
Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) - Apache Lounge VS17 Server build (Strangely it logs VS17 in the error log when I shut down the server, but the installation file name reads as vs16)
PHP/8.3.6 as an Apache module
Windows 11 machine.
httpd.conf:
LoadModule php_module "d:/Program Files/php-8.3.6-Win32-vs16-x64/php8apache2_4.dll"

PHPIniDir "D:/Program Files/php-8.3.6-Win32-vs16-x64"

php.ini:
extension_dir = "D:/Program Files/php-8.3.6-Win32-vs16-x64/ext"

I tried all these three, none of them has worked:
extension=curl

extension= php_curl.dll

extension="D:\Program Files\php-8.3.6-Win32-vs16-x64\ext\curl\php_curl.dll"

When I start the server, I get an error log like this:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library curl (tried: D:/Program Files/php-8.3.6-Win32-vs16-x64/ext\curl (The specified module could not be found), D:/Program Files/php-8.3.6-Win32-vs16-x64/ext\php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
[Wed May 08 12:30:20.591092 2024] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 34228:tid 408] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

What am I supposed to do to make the curl load correctly?

this seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348/php-curl-on-windows-install-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

Thanks. All I needed to do was to restart the computer after adding the php directory to the PATH environmental variable.
